# Is there anyway to print while getchar didn't receive a newline yet

Tags: c, printing, getchar

I want to print newline ('\n') when capturing space char (' ') while reading strings char by char using getchar().
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c;
    int nl;

    nl=0; /* holds number of consecutive newline char */

    while (nl<2) {
    /* the loops  ends when getchar() receives
       two consecutive newline inputs */
       c=getchar();
       if (c==' ')
           putchar('\n');
       else if (c=='\n')
           nl++;
       else
           nl=0; 
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The program doesn't print anything until it receives newline char ('\n')

I'm using: gcc version 3.4.2

Comment: you're interested in multithreading I believe.

Comment: @GershomMaes I don't think the problem is that complicated

Comment: @SimpleJ you're right - I was mislead by the title and didn't read the question carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, under normal circumstances, the terminal you're providing input on starts in "canonical mode", where the kernel buffers all input (and provides basic line editing, e.g. backspace) until enter is pressed, then sends the data over the device as a unit.

You can disable this behavior by turning off the `ICANON` bit of the `c_lflag` member of the `termios` structure, using the `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr` functions (be sure to restore the old mode before your program exits), but then you'll have a lot of work to do to get back the original line-editing behavior if you want it. You might also want to turn off other flags like enter/newline conversion, echoing of input, etc. depending on your usage case.

Some people may tell you to also disable buffering at the stdio level via calling `setvbuf` on `stdin`, but this should not be necessary and will degrade performance.

Comment: it seems a little bit complicated, but i will look for it. thank you :)